# html5 canvas scaling without specifying dimensions

Tags: html, canvas

I've just started working with the html5 canvas element.

I'm using the latest firefox and chromium browsers.  And so far, they're
responding alike.

What I'm trying to achieve is scaling of an image without having to
specify the canvas or image drawing sizes.  I'd like the canvas to fill
the browser window, and for the image to fill the canvas without
specifying any sizes.  And to readjust canvas and its image on the
fly when the user adjusts the browser's frame.

The mansion pic that I'm testing with is 4284x2844.

I've managed to achieve dynamic scaling, but there's a problem...
if I don't specify sizes the image becomes blurry.

This is my first stackoverflow question and I haven't conquered the
formatting.  So, please take a look at the small amount of code over
at pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/88faqJUx

Thank you for your help.

I found the solution...

Adding two lines, with no other changes, did the trick, though at this point I'm not exactly sure
why it was originally failing, but thoroughly happy to move on...

```
<canvas id="taba_main_canvas">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</ canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var main_canvas=document.getElementById("taba_main_canvas");
    var cxt=main_canvas.getContext("2d");


    // adding these next two lines solved the blurriness issues        

    //Set the canvas width to the same as the browser
    main_canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    main_canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


    var img=new Image();
    <!-- mansion pic 4284x2844 -->
    img.src="images/mansion_3344.png";

    img.onload = function()
    {
         <!-- use the graphics full size and scale the canvas in css -->
        cxt.drawImage(img,0,0,main_canvas.width,main_canvas.height);

    }

</script>
```

Just one tiny little problem, the vertical size of the image is apparently just a few lines taller
than the canvas and so I get a vertival scrollbar.  Dragging the browser window taller, which normally
would eliminate the vertical scrollbar has no effect. I've tried manipulating the canvas or image height
in the code, but that didn't change anything.

Still, having the image look clean is a big win.  I'm moving on for the moment and will revisit this
later.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this is to latch on to the document `onresize` event and resize the canvas by using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` or some such thing. I've used it that way myself, but that was for something which I didn't care about IE support - see [W3C DOM Compatibility - CSS Object Model View](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html) at quirksmode for info about browser support. Note also that the scrollbar width *is* included in `innerWidth` and `innerHeight`; if your page may need scrolling, you may wish to do something like subtract 20 and pad the containing element with a suitable background colour.

I presume that you're not just trying to draw an image - if you were just doing that, `<img>` would be a much better match.

Edit: jQuery has `$(document).width();` and `$(document).height();` which seem to get the right figures. Another edit: actually they're wrong; they're the document width and height, not viewport width and height, so I think innerWidth and innerHeight may be all there is.

Comment: @mjbjr77: what solution?  What why?